# embedding ARM assembly in C language

Tags: c, assembly, arm

My goal is to implement sorting algorithm using C language.
I have to make a C code that converts into least number of instructions when compiled by gcc -O0(no optimization option) in ARM machine.
So, My idea is to embed quicksort implemented in assembly directly into C code.
I referred to several following documents and tried to implement my goal.
However, I don't know how to put intarray into my assembly function 'QuickSort' as a parameter.

Reference
1.https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#ARM_Assembly
2.http://forum.falinux.com/zbxe/index.php?mid=lecture_tip&comment_srl=517498&sort_index=readed_count&order_type=asc&l=fr&page=58&document_srl=567970    (sorry for non-english website)

I'm newbie in assembly.
Please help me..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int Quicksort(uint32_t intarray[]);

asm(
".global Quicksort\n\
Quicksort:\n\
qsort:\n\
    stmfd   sp!,{r4, r6, lr}     \n\
    mov     r6,r2                \n\
qsort_tailcall_entry:\n\
    sub     r7,r6,r1\n\
    cmp     r7,#1\n\
    ldmlefd sp!,{r4,r6,pc}\n\
    ldr     r7,[r0,r1,asl#2]\n\
    add     r2,r1,#1\n\
    mov     r4,r6\n\
partition_loop:\n\
    ldr     r3,[r0, r2, asl #2]\n\
    cmp     r3,r7\n\
    addle   r2,r2, #1\n\
    ble     partition_test\n\
    sub     r4,r4, #1\n\
    ldr     r5,[r0, r4, asl #2]\n\
    str     r5,[r0, r2, asl #2]\n\
    str     r3,[r0, r4, asl #2]\n\
partition_test:\n\
    cmp     r2,r4\n\
    blt     partition_loop\n\
partition_finish:\n\
    sub     r2,r2,#1\n\
    ldr     r3,[r0,r2,asl #2]\n\
    str     r3,[r0,r1,asl #2]\n\
    str     r7,[r0,r2,asl #2]\n\
    bl      qsort\n\
    mov     r1,r4\n\
    b       qsort_tailcall_entry\n\
"
);


int main(void){
    uint32_t intarray[10] = {5,2,5,1,7,5,7,2,3,8};
    Quicksort(intarray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read this [document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf)
I guess you need to use registers r0 to r3 for storing the function argument.
Look at Section 5.5

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632752/matrix-multiplication-in-arm-assembly) might help.

Comment: Why can't you use an optimization level other than `-O0`?

Comment: What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: @fuz I guess it is for learning how to write a size optimized code without using compiler optimization.

Comment: @Gaurav Pathak That's right. I'm taking a computer architecture course, and it is from my term project. I guess my professor intends to teach me how to write optimized c code. To make grading homework fair, there is a gcc -O0 compile requirement

Comment: @Gaurav Pathak 
I succeed in putting parameter in assembly code.
However, I got another issue. Please help me.... Thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423872/embedding-arm-assembly-in-c-language-compile-error

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are compiling with gcc, you could use the gcc `asm` extension (as the name says, it's a gcc extension and might not be compatible with other compilers). Take a look at [basic asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm) and [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm). Since you will probably be accessing data from your C code, I advise you to stick with the advanced version which lets you specify memory operands.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you help me with another issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423872/embedding-arm-assembly-in-c-language-compile-error
Thank you.