# embedding ARM assembly in C language compile error

Tags: c, assembly, arm

My assignment is to implement sorting algorithm using C language. I have to make a C code that converts into least number of instructions when compiled by gcc -o0(no optimization option) in ARM machine.

So, My idea is to compile with -o1 option first and embed the compiled assembly  directly into my C code.

I succeed in compiling with -o1 option. However, when I compiled the same code with -o0 option, I got a following assembler messages.
Please help me...

```
user@debian-armel:~gcc -g -O0 mycode4.c -o mycode4
/tmp/cc2Q2Tbh.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc2Q2Tbh.s:77: Warning: destination register same as write-back base
```

this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define nMAX 5
#define rMAX 1024




void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int* arr0=arr;
    int left0=left;
    int right0=right;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
"quicksort:\n\t"
"push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, lr}\n\t"
"mov     r5, %0\n\t"
"mov     r6, %2\n\t"
"add     r3, %1, %2\n\t"
"add     r3, r3, r3, lsr #31\n\t"
"asr     r3, r3, #1\n\t"
"ldr     ip, [%0, r3, lsl #2]\n\t"
"add     sl, %0, %1, lsl #2\n\t"
"add     r8, %1, #1\n\t"
"b       quicksort+0x2c\n\t"
"add     r8, r8, #1\n\t"
"sub     r4, r8, #1\n\t"
"ldr     r9, [sl], #4\n\t"
"cmp     ip, r9\n\t"
"bgt     quicksort+0x28\n\t"
"add     r7, r5, %2, lsl #2\n\t"
"ldr     %0, [r5, %2, lsl #2]\n\t"
"cmp     ip, %0\n\t"
"bge     quicksort+0x68\n\t"
"sub     r3, %2, #1\n\t"
"add     r3, r5, r3, lsl #2\n\t"
"sub     %2, %2, #1\n\t"
"mov     r7, r3\n\t"
"ldr     %0, [r3], #-4\n\t"
"cmp     ip, %0\n\t"
"blt     quicksort+0x54\n\t"
"cmp     %2, r4\n\t"
"blt     quicksort+0x88\n\t"
"str     %0, [sl, #-4]\n\t"
"str     r9, [r7]\n\t"
"mov     r4, r8\n\t"
"sub     %2, %2, #1\n\t"
"cmp     r8, %2\n\t"
"ble     quicksort+0x28\n\t"
"cmp     %1, %2\n\t"
"movlt   %0, r5\n\t"
"bllt    quicksort\n\t"
"cmp     r6, r4\n\t"
"movgt   %0, r5\n\t"
"movgt   %1, r4\n\t"
"movgt   %2, r6\n\t"
"blgt    quicksort\n\t"
"pop     {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, lr}\n\t"
"bx      lr\n\t"
:

:
"r"(arr0),
"r"(left0),
"r"(right0)
:

);
}




int main(void){
    uint32_t intarray[5]={5,39,2,44,23};

    quickSort(intarray,0,nMAX-1);
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d",intarray[0],intarray[1],intarray[2],intarray[3],intarray[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the assembly code that GCC generates (`gcc -O0 -S mycode4.c`) you'll probably see that it expanded one of your instructions as `ldr r3, [r3], #-4`. That's because you said it could use any register for operand 0 (`"r"(arr0)`) and you never gave any reason to believe R3 was being used for something else. It could've even chose LR as the register which would mean LR wouldn't contain the return address like your code assumes. You should just write this code in plain assembly. It's much simpler than GCC's difficult to get right inline assembly statement.

Comment: Double check whether using assmbly code (which code created by an optimising compiler) fits your assignment. I have a feeling that the lesson of the assignment is missed that way.

Comment: @RossRidge gcc extended inline assembly is actually pretty easy to write. It's just that the OP apparently tried to paste regular assembly as inline assembly, which is the real problem.